# How to change freemarker file in web project at runtime?

Tags: java, freemarker

I use embedded jetty, osgi in my web project.

I want to change the code in freemarker files in the web project at runtime. What is the best way to realize it?

Best regards.

Comment: You want to apply templating - to a template?

Comment: I can change the code in freemarker files using eclipse editors during the development time, without shutdown the jetty service. So I wonder if I can do the same thing at runtime in a deployment environment.

Comment: I know. **This is what Freemarker is for** If there is something to cahnge, that should come from the **context**. If there is something to change, that should be handled by the template itself, rendering the part that needs to be changeable using the functionality it has.  (BTW, on jboss, if you changed the file and removed it from the caches, you could do this without shutdown)

Comment: Frankly, changing sources on the fly is a chancy proposition. I would strongly suggest that you re-factor your freemarker source file to a number of file fragments that you can `include` based on context variables.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the templates will be replaced under the control of the Web application, when you know a template has been replaced, you could call `Configuration.removeTemplateFromCache` on it, so that it will be guaranteed that the next `Configuration.getTemplate` will return the new file. This also means that you don't have to set a low `template_update_delay` on the production server.

The more tricky question is if FreeMarker can accidentally see a partially replaced or exclusively locked (can't open it) file while you are replacing it. During development you don't care because it has near 0 chance, but on a production server you do. This is up to the `TemplateLoader` implementation, and then the storage behind it. Like if it's DB-backed, there's certainly no such risk. For `File`-s, I guess there can be such glitches. Unfortunately, you can't force FreeMarker to keep a template in the template-cache while you are replacing it. But you can achieve something very similar on the `TemplateLoader`-level instead. You could create a custom `TemplateLoader` to which you can tell something like `myTemplateLoader.mirrorToMemory(fileName)`, then you replace the file, then you call `myTemplateLoader.releaseMirrorOf(fileName)`. And then you invalidate the template-cache entry as I said earlier.